# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'price'

Tags: python, linked-list

As a homework I have got to do a Linked List with Nodes as its objects while nodes would carry the `Car class` as their data. Not sure if I'm doing this right, but my friends tried to help me and this is what I have:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, identification = None, name = None, brand = None, 
        price = None, active = None):
            self.identification = identification
            self.name = name
            self.brand = brand
            self.price = price
            self.active = active

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.prevNode = None
        self.nextNode = None
        self.data = data

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insertNode(self, car):
        newNode = Node(car)
        curNode = self.head
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = newNode
        elif newNode.data.price < curNode.data.price:
            newNode.nextNode = self.head
            self.head.prevNode = newNode
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            while curNode.nextNode is not None and curNode.nextNode.data.price <= newNode.data.price:
                curNode = curNode.nextNode
            newNode.nextNode = curNode.nextNode
            curNode.nextNode = newNode

db = LinkedList()

def init(cars):
    for car in cars:
        db.insertNode(car)

def add(car):
    db.insertNode(car)

def updateName(identification, name):
    curNode = db.head
    while curNode.data.id != identification:
        curNode = curNode.next
    curNode.data.name = name

def activateCar(identification):
    curNode = db.head
    while curNode.data.id != identification:
        curNode = curNode.next
    curNode.data.active = True

def calculateCarPrice():
    total = 0
    for i in range(db):
        if db[i].data.active == True:
            total += db[i].data.price
        i += 1
    return total

car1 = (1, 'a', 'audi', 3000, True)
car2 = (1, 'b', 'bmw', 5000, False)
cars = [car1, car2]
init(cars)
```

In my eyes, everything should be OK, but it returns this error when I call the `init` function.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Matyas/Desktop/ZAL/Cvičení/showroom.py", line 89, in
>
> > init(cars)
>
> File "C:/Users/Matyas/Desktop/ZAL/Cvičení/showroom.py", line 40, in init
>
> > db.insertNode(car)
>
> File "C:/Users/Matyas/Desktop/ZAL/Cvičení/showroom.py", line 26, in insertNode
>
> > elif newNode.data.price < curNode.data.price:
>
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'price'

I don't understand why it even returns '`tuple`'..

Comment: Your cars are tuples. You meant to do `car1 = Car(1, 'a', 'audi', 3000, True)` and `car2 = Car(1, 'b', 'bmw', 5000, False)`

Comment: Thanks, I'm such an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have written

```
car1 = (1, 'a', 'audi', 3000, True)
car2 = (1, 'b', 'bmw', 5000, False)
```

Should say

```
car1 = Car(1, 'a', 'audi', 3000, True)
car2 = Car(1, 'b', 'bmw', 5000, False)
```